# Differences between Android and iOS when using Google Analytics in PhoneGap 1.2.0

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-analytics

I've been trying to get Google Analytics to work in PhoneGap 1.2.0 over Android and iOS.

What are the main differences between Android and iOS when using Google Analytics in PhoneGap 1.2.0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The three main components required and the different parts for Android and iOS.

1. **GAP-alytics** from [phonegap-plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins])

   - Android

     - GoogleAnalyticsTracker.java
     - analytics.js
   - iOS

     - GoogleAnalyticsPlugin.h / GoogleAnalyticsPlugin.m
     - GoogleAnalyticsPlugin.js
2. **Google Analytics** from [Google](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/)

   - Android

     - libGoogleAnalytics.jar (no source available)
   - iOS        - *these are included with the phonegap plugin for convenience*

     - libGoogleAnalytics.a (no source available)
     - GANTracker.h
3. **PhoneGap** from [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)

   - Android

     - add `<plugin name="GoogleAnalyticsTracker" value="com.package.path.to.class.GoogleAnalyticsTracker"/>` to res/xml/plugins.xml file
   - iOS

     - In “Supporting Files/PhoneGap.plist” file add:
     - Plugins:

       - key = googleAnalytics (name used in the javascript)    Value = GoogleAnalytics (name of Obj-C object)
     - External Hosts

       - ‘*’ (without quotes) as Item 0

NB: Remember that even though the iOS and Android versions have a `phonegap-1.2.0.js` file they are **NOT** the same file. The code is different and you can't just copy it between platforms. Make sure your app uses the appropriate version.

---

**Android Javascript**

```
window.plugins.googleAnalytics.start ("your UA code",       //UA-account ID
         function() { console.log("started") },             //successCallBack
         function() { console.log("didn't start") }         //failureCallBack
);



window.plugins.googleAnalytics.trackPageView (          //**NB**: NOTE CAPITAL 'V'
               "/Main Page",                                    //Page  (include /)
               function() {console.log("tracked page view")},           //successCallBack   
               function() {console.log("didn't track page view")}       //failureCallBack
);


window.plugins.googleAnalytics.trackEvent (
            "Contact",                                          //Category
            "Email",                                            //Action
            “John Smith”,                                       //Label
            0,                                                  //Value
            function() { console.log("tracked event") },        //successCallBack
            function() { console.log("didn't track event") }    //failureCallBack
);
```

---

**iOS Javascript**

```
window.plugins.googleAnalyticsPlugin.startTrackerWithAccountID(“your UA code”); 

window.plugins.googleAnalyticsPlugin.trackPageview(whichPage); //Note lowercase v in trackPageview.    

window.plugins.googleAnalyticsPlugin. googleAnalytics.trackEvent(
    "Contact",
    "Email",
    “John Smith”
    0, 
    function() { console.log("tracked event") },            //successCallBack
    function() { console.log("didn't track event") }        //failureCallBack
);
```

**NB**. the variable ‘whichpage’ MUST be preceded with a forwardslash (/). Android will let you away without this. iOS will NOT.