# Step by step to get Google Analytics working in PhoneGap 1.2.0 on iOS (phonegapalytics)

Tags: ios, cordova, google-analytics

How do I install Google Analytics in PhoneGap 1.2.0 in iOS?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First and foremost I have to give a lot of credit to the guys [here.](http://www.countermarch.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/10/31/PhoneGap-1x-Google-Analytics-and-XCode-42) Their blog was of tremendous help but I still had to do a few more things to finally get it to work.

I’m going to go through it step by step so that you can get it to work at a very basic level and then you can take it from there. I found that even the *slightest* mistake can mess things up.

I am assuming you have installed PhoneGap 1.2.0 and are using Xcode 4.2

---

**PART A**

Get a basic PhoneGap app working. Follow the [PhoneGap guide](http://phonegap.com/start#ios-x4) and get that working.

---

**PART B**

Download the PhoneGap Google Analytics Plugin. 
I find the easiest thing to do is just download the zip file from [here.](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins) You get a pile of things you don't need but it doesn't matter.

Expand the file in your download directory. Go into the expanded directory.. into the *iPhone* folder and you should see the *GoogleAnalytics* folder.

In Xcode, right click on project (the blue block thing at the top) and choose 'Add files to '. Navigate to the expanded folder. Click on the 'GoogleAnalytics' folder. Make sure the 'copy files into destination group's folder (if necessary)' is selected and that its added to the target. Click 'Add'. Drag the **files in the folder** in Xcode to the Plugins folder.

Go back to Finder and open the project directory. Copy the `GoogleAnalyticsPlugin.js` from the GoogleAnalytics folder to the 'www' folder. Xcode will give a warning about re-saving the file.. Just click Close.

Go to the index.html file. In `function onDeviceReady()` add the following line to the start of the function.

`window.plugins.googleAnalyticsPlugin.startTrackerWithAccountID("YOUR UA CODE");`

Next add the following function under the `onDeviceReady` function (inside the same script block)

```
function trackpage(id)
{
    console.log("start trackpage: " + id);
    window.plugins.googleAnalyticsPlugin.trackPageview(id);
    console.log("end trackpage: " + id);
}
```

Now, still in the index.html file, find the line

```
<li>Check your console log for any white-list rejection errors.</li>
```

(remember this is phonegap 1.2.0)

add the following line after it.

```
<li class="arrow"><a href="javascript:trackpage('/TEST');">test analytics</a></li>
```

This gives a link you can click on in the test app.

NB. You **MUST** have a forward slash (/) in the page your are tracking. So `javascript:trackpage('/TEST')` will work while `javascript:trackpage('TEST')` will NOT.

Finally, still in the index.html add the following line

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="GoogleAnalyticsPlugin.js"></script>
```

below

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
```

Don't bother trying to run it yet. It won't work.

---

**PART C**

Next goto the `GoogleAnalytics.h` file. Just wipe it.. There are a pile of problems here. JSON seems to be now JSONKit and PhoneGapCommand is now PGPlugin.. Just paste this in. The PhoneGap documentation seems to be all over the place.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#ifdef PHONEGAP_FRAMEWORK
#import <PhoneGap/PGPlugin.h>
#import <PhoneGap/NSData+Base64.h>
#import <PhoneGap/JSONKit.h> 
#else
#import "PGPlugin.h"
#import "NSData+Base64.h"
#import "JSONKit.h" 
#endif

#import "GANTracker.h"

@interface GoogleAnalyticsPlugin : PGPlugin<GANTrackerDelegate> {

}

- (void) startTrackerWithAccountID:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;
- (void) trackEvent:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;
- (void) trackPageview:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;

@end
```

---

**PART D**

Next add the Google Analytics part to the project. This is the part which Google provides but its conveniently included in the phonegap ios GoogleAnalytics/GoogSDK plugin folder.

In Xcode, go to the `GoogleAnalytics/GoogSDK` folder and drag the `GANTracker.h` and `libGoogleAnalytics.a` files to the Plugins directory.

Basically you need to copy them from the ‘blue’ `GoogleAnalytics/GoogSDK` folder into a ‘yellow’ folder so they can be found by header files.

---

**PART E**

Next we need to add sqlite (where Google Analytics stores data when not online) and CFNetwork (so Google Analytics can upload the data) to the project.

In Xcode click on the project (the blue thing at the top of the file). Click on the main target. Then click on the Build Phases.  The 3rd item on the list is the “Link Binary with Libraries”. Note there are two of these.. choose the top one. Open it and click on the + sign. Add `libsqlite3.0.dylib` then add `CFNetwork.framework`.

---

**PART F**

Finally (almost there) we need to setup the plugin. Go to the `PhoneGap.plist` file. Under Plugins add another entry with the key as `googleAnalyticsPlugin` (the javascript name) and the value as `GoogleAnalyticsPlugin` (the Obj-C part).

Under ExternalHosts add a `*` entry

Now try and run. Fingers crossed it will work.

The best way to test it to run the program and then use the new Google Analytics Real Time (BETA) mode as you can see pages being tracked live.

You need to change to the new version of Google Analytics (it should be an obvious link at the top to move to the new version). Open the GA account, go to Home..REAL_TIME... Overview. 
You should see the TEST page track coming in within a few seconds.

Note: You can't track events in realtime. You need to wait for them to be processed.

**ISSUES**

I had some problems when looking at the *Compile Sources* and *Link Binary With Libraries*. The GoogleAnalytics parts would show up in red. If they are in red it means your project can't find them and I think how you resolve this depends on your version of Xcode so you might need to google about a bit to resolve that. What I did was to remove the GoogleAnalytics (press the - sign) then drag the file in. If it shows up as a "proper icon" (as opposed to a red box) it should have worked.

**Doing it on Android also?**

I assume if you are using Phonegap you are probably doing an Android version also. If this is case you may want to check out [this comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8094604/516286) Q+A for the differences.

Comment: Waw, is like a book. Nice job :)

Comment: Thanks. Its the result of about a week of frustrating hacking. Hopefully it will help others avoid wasting a lot of time.

Comment: @Tim Thank you very much man, was looking for this too. Btw, for hosts, don't need ExternalHosts to be *. You can set up google-analytics.com that is the domain where the requests are sent.

Comment: you're welcome. Yep I knew about the external hosts.. I just set it to * so there was less chance of having this as a point of failure.

Comment: Excellent write up! This really helped me. I had one problem where the GoogleAnalyticsPlugin could not be found and I had to go back and add the files as a group and not a reference. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: @MattyB thank you for that. Glad to be of help.. took me ages to write it semi-coherently! I come from an Eclipse/Android background and I am forever getting confused with Xcode's groups/references/blue folders/yellow folders.

Comment: I'm trying your instructions and it is complaining about the new header code you've provided.

GoogleAnalytics/GoogleAnalyticsPlugin.h:8:9: 'PGPlugin.h' file not found

Comment: i have implemented the following steps.but i could not found it them on google analyitc login tracker real time

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much for your great work, my only confusion was with this block:

```
function trackpage(id)
{
    console.log("start trackpage: " + id);
    window.plugins.googleAnalyticsPlugin.trackPageview(id);
    console.log("end trackpage: " + id);
}
```

Had to put it outside the `onready` function for it to work in my app.