# Google Anlytics plugin for Phonegap Error

Tags: cordova, google-analytics

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097015/step-by-set-to-get-google-analytics-working-in-phonegap-1-2-0-on-ios-phonegapal) great step-by-step guide to implement the GA plugin in my Cordova project.
I ran the app, and click on the "test analytics" link (as added according to the guide), and there was a successful hit to analytics.
The problem is that about 5 seconds afterwards, I got this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-
[GoogleAnalyticsPlugin hitDispatched:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x869e2c0'
```

Can someone help in solving this problem?

I'm using xcode 4.3.3, Cordova 1.6.1.

Thank you in advanced!