# Google Analytics on HTML Iphone App

Tags: ios4, google-analytics, phonegap-plugins

Hi I just tried to follow this link:

[Step by step to get Google Analytics working in PhoneGap 1.2.0 on iOS (phonegapalytics)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097015/step-by-set-to-get-google-analytics-working-in-phonegap-1-2-0-on-ios-phonegapal/12255106#12255106)

But in Part B, third para, last line "Drag the files in the folder in Xcode to the Plugins folder." , I am unable to get that which files from where need to drag where? because when i did add it automatically fetches google analytics in xcode and shows under project name.

Another thing, there is no such function `function onDeviceReady()` in my index.html under www. It just contains the HTML.

Can I create one?